# Can not delete a mysql user in ubuntu server

Tags: permissions, mysql, users

I wanted to ask how can i delete a user in mysql on ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. I have many users and was creating new to test something out but now i get an error deleting it. The error i get is:

```
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for 'someuser'@'%'
```

and also tried it localhost instead of % but i still get the same error..
Tried to grant and revoke privileges but nothing helps.. The user is still here and not deleted..
the command i tried is this:

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'someuser'@'localhost' with grant option;
REVOKE GRANT OPTION ON *.* FROM 'someuser'@'localhost';
```

previosly i deleted a user with query DELETE user FROM mysql.users WHERE user = 'user1'; and it was successfully deleted but than i got an error when i wanted to create the same user1 again.. It showed me error that a user can not be created:

```
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'user1'@'127.0.0.1'
```

I really can not understand what is the problem with this mysql but it makes me very nervous.. I need this users to be deleted and than user1 to be recreated..

Can you please help me. Thank you

Comment: Did you try to 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES' at some point?  This causes MySQL to reread privileges.

Comment: yes after executing grant and revoke commands.. It won;t work with that either.. i do not know what to do...

Comment: I think the site 'Database administrators' would be more appropriate for your question, which is not specific to Ubuntu.

Comment: Also, have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698335/error-1396-hy000-operation-drop-user-failed-for-userlocalhost

Comment: ok i will have a look and let you know. Thank you

Comment: i resolved my issue.. i should have used drop user 'user1'@'localhost' command.. i am sure i used it previously but it did not execute correctly because i could not create user after that.. now everything is ok and next time i will use 'localhost' instead of 127.0.0.1 when creating user.. thank you again for your help. cheers

Comment: Glad to see it was solved.

Answer (score -1):

i resolved my issue.. i should have used drop user 'user1'@'localhost' command.. i am sure i used it previously but it did not execute correctly because i could not create user after that.. now everything is ok and next time i will use 'localhost' instead of 127.0.0.1 when creating user.. thank you again for your help. cheers